# Elasticsearch 6.3.0 on Kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy production grade Elasticsearch 6.3.0 on Kubernetes.

Came across few articles, but still not sure what is the best approach to go with.

1. https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster

It doesn't use stateful set.

2. https://anchormen.nl/blog/big-data-services/elastic-search-deployment-kubernetes/

This is pretty old.

Using elastic search for App search.

Images from Elasticsearch are

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.0
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.3.0
```

I would like to go with -oss image and it is the core Apache one.

Is there any good documentation on setting up production grade 6.3.0 version on Kubernetes.

Comment: Do you really need a `StatefulSet`? We are running an ElasticSearch cluster based on Deployments like the one by `pires` just fine. I think his documentation on Github and his manifests are a solid base to start from and you can just change the `Deployment` to a `StatefulSet` if you believe it is the better choice for you.

Comment: The proper production grade setup and configuration is dependent on your use case anyway :)

Comment: If not stateful, what will happen to the data when the pod gets restarted or when deployed to other pod for some other reason.

Comment: _what will happen to the data when the pod gets restarted or when deployed to other pod for some other reason_ conflates two concepts that are not related to one another: pod restarts, and persistent data. A `Pod` restart is zero drama, so long as the `volumes:` are correctly declared because that's kubernetes' job, `StatefulSet` or `Deployment` will behave the same. The **difference** between the two is whether a `volume` is **tied to a Pod's identity**, such as `db-0` always needs to start up with `db-0`'s data, in contrast to "fine, startup with _any_ data so long as it persists over time"

Comment: I also will say that in regard to your "production grade ES cluster" question, **ensure** and I mean **ensure** that your `volume` provider has enough IOPS to support an ES cluster, because those things will thrash a disk for sure. In AWS, you'll want `io1` with as many provisioned IOPS as you can afford, because it is **bad news** to have an ES cluster driving the load average high on a Node because of the blocking I/O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most promising new developments for running Elasticearch on Kubernetes is the [Elasticsearch Operator](https://github.com/upmc-enterprises/elasticsearch-operator).

Kubernetes [Operators](https://coreos.com/operators/) allow for more sophistication when it comes to dealing with the requirements of complex tools (and Elasticsearch is definitely one). Especially when considering the need to avoid losing Elasticsearch data, an operator is the way to go.